# python replace backslash and single quote

Tags: python

I have the this code:

```
'Tokyo\'s'.replace(r'\"', '&quot;').replace(r"\'", '&apos;')
```

I already looked at some of the old StackOverflow topics regarding this issue but couldn't figure out.

I still get the same result back `Tokyo\'s`

result looking for is `Tokyo&apos;s`

I am trying to convert them to XML escaped char

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/xml-escaped-chars.html

also tried using `escape("'")` which gives me `\'` back.

Your suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output? I ran the code and it gave me `Tokyo's`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the escape `\`:

```
'Tokyo\'s'.replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&apos;')
```

This will return `'Tokyo&apos;s'`

When using `r"\'"` as the target to replace, it will look for the pattern `\'` exactly. That pattern doesn't exist in your original string `Tokyo's`.

Note: The original string is *not* `Tokyo\'s`, because the `\'` in this string is escaping `'`

Comment: @Ann Zen From the question it looks like they want quotes and apostrophes to be converted to `&quote;` and `&apos;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Tokyo\'s'.replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&apos;'))
```

should work, but in general, if you want characters replaced with HTML entities, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml

Answer (score 0):

You may gain more flexibility here and cleaner code using `translate()`:

```
table = str.maketrans({'"': '&quot;',
                       "'": '&apos;'
                       }
                      )

print('Tokyo\'s'.translate(table))
```

Ouput:

```
Tokyo&apos;s
```